# Bash snippet for apache error log to show what URLS are causing 404s?

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, logging, snippet

I have a standard apache error log file. I would like to see what URLs are causing 404s, since I have moved this site around and I want to find bad links. Can anyone recommend a bash snippet that will parse this log using awk or something to show me the popular 404s?

I know there are advanced programmes for this sort of thing. I'm just looking for something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
grep ' 404 ' /var/log/apache2/access.log | cut -d ' ' -f 7 |sort |uniq -c |sort -n
```

Comment: Add a "| sort -n" to get them in order of hits

Comment: I agree with this solution with one important side note: This works with most Apache installations that use the system default logging format. If the admin has changed the logging format the command above must be altered slightly.

Answer (score 3):

An awk answer :

```
awk '$9 == 404{urls[$7]++}END{for (url in urls) print urls[url] "\t" url}' access_log | sort -n
```

It's just for fun as it's probably much much slower than womble solution

Comment: Got in just as I was writing mine.

Comment: Have you a nice solution to include the sort -n in awk ? I did not found a way to do it in a simple way